# Concatenate VARBINARY Data in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, pdf, ms-word, blob

We have an application that stores Word and PDF documents in a share on a server.  I'm looking into the possibility of storing these as BLOBs in the associated Microsoft SQL database instead, which seems like it's probably a good idea.

Separately, an idea which I'm investigating is the possibility of allowing users to easily view all of the documents in the share associated with a case (let's imagine they're grouped into folders by case) as one continuous stream on a tablet, as if they were all one big PDF file.

I think I've worked out how to do the latter, running a web service to convert the Word documents to PDFs and then concatenate them and the extant PDFs.  But that's if we continue to store the documents as files in an NTFS share.  What if we stored the documents as BLOBs in MSSQL instead?

Is there a way to concatenate BLOB data so that for every, say, 10 BLOB records (which might represent Word or PDF files), I could create an 11th record which was a concatenation of the other 10 as one giant PDF?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Blobs are not an effective way of storing files. SQL 2008 bought about a better mechanism for this called FILESTREAM ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx) which can store the files directly on the file system but managed by SQL.

As for the files you would not be able to simply concatenate the PDF files to form one continuous file but there are several libraries that you could use to do this, potentially on the fly. This would remove the need to store the concatenated document as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not sure your assessment of BLOBs is correct, though. I know about FILESTREAM, but reading around the subject has revealed that for smaller documents (~1MB seems to be about the threshold) it's actually more efficient NOT to use FILESTREAM.  Of course, without FILESTREAM we're limited to files up to 2GB, but that's fine.